# Reset audit upon observable emits a value

Tags: rxjs

The original code I have is the following: there are two observables I combine with `combineLatest`. `a$` emits 4 times per second so there is an `audit` depending on current `b$` value. I then takes the value of `c$` to make calculations with values of `a$` and `c$`.
What I actually need is to skip `audit` if `c$` emits a value and proceed to calculations without delay. I tried number of approaches with `switchMap` but it didn't work.

```
combineLatest(a$, b$).pipe(
  audit((_, b) => {
    if (b == 1) {
      return interval(5000);
    }
    return interval(1000);
  }),
  withLatestFrom(c$)
)
.subscribe(([[a, _], c]) => {
  // calculations with a and c
});
```

Comment: I have a hard time understanding this.

So you do some calculations with $a and $c. But, when c has not emmited, you add an audit that depends on $b. But when it emits, you want to stop auditing and want to go ahead and do your calculations. Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct. `c$` emits rarely and most of the time its value is the same, but when its emit, it could wait on the audit of 5 seconds but I would like to make calculations with the new value of `c$` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comment section:

a$ and c$ are used to calculate stuff. But c$ rarely emits. We use b$ to add a wait time on the observable, but we don't want this to happen when c$ emits.

My solution was this... but I have not tested it. Let me know what you think:

```
// a$ used to calculate
// b$ decides whether wait 5s or 1s
// c$ when emits, we should skip audit
// this assumes they all emit at least once. If not, we could add to
// any single one of them `startWith(value)`, like `c$.pipe(startWith(0))`
```

import { of, interval, combineLatest } from "rxjs";
import { startWith, pairwise, concatMap, take, delay } from "rxjs/operators";

const a$ = interval(500);
const b$ = of(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
const c$ = interval(5000).pipe(startWith(-1));

```
combineLatest(a$, b$, c$)
  .pipe(
    pairwise(), // get previous state as well as new in array
    concatMap(([prev, curr]) => {
      // put names so I understand what I'm doing
      const currA = curr[0];
      const currB = curr[1];
      const currC = curr[2];
      const prevC = prev[2];

      if (currC === prevC) {
        // only return the audit if C didn't change
        return of([currA, currB, currC]).pipe(throttleTime(currB === 1 ? 5000 : 1000));
      }

      return of([currA, currB, currC]);
      // return of([]);
    }),
    take(10)
  )
  .subscribe(([a, _, c]) => {
    // math
  });
```

There's probably a more elegant solution, but I'd have to think a bit and also understand better what `a`, `b` and `c` are. Still, hope this helps

Edit: I updated my answer here.
Edit2: Updated again to use `throttleTime`

Comment: Also it's worth mentioning this would probably be cleaner if we separate concerns... meaning, b does 1 thing, so its one stream. a and c do another, so its another stream... and we end up joining them in a Subject somewhere

Comment: The piece of code in question actually controls playback rate of a stream, so, `a$` is a real latency, `b$` is a playback rate and `c$` is a target latency value to catchup by adjusting playback rate.
I like you solution, I will give it a try ASAP!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected. As expected it got into `concatMap` frequently (as a$ emits values) and returns with audited observable but it quite rarely got to the subscription block. Actually it only got to the subscription block when c$ emits and it returns from the `concatMap` without audit. In other cases it looks like it's get lost.

Comment: I tested my solution on a playground, and updated with what I understand you are trying to achieve.

Let me know if this is the case, otherwise I might have misunderstood

Comment: I gotta add that I added a `startWith` pipe to c$ obs so I dont have to wait for it's first emission to kickstart the stream

Comment: I will take a look shortly! TY for you efforts!
UPD: I do not think it will work. The point of audit to skip source values for a period of time. With delay it would just, well, delay them but then they still will arrive too frequently.

Comment: You're right,

you could swap delay with `audit().pipe(take(1))` to avoid it going forever, or as many takes as you need. You could also use `throttleTime` to get the desired wait time and get the last emission.